# ionic 2 image doesn't show up in android phone

Tags: android, ionic2

I have a problem in ionic2 , my image doesn't show up in my android phone 
its run normally in localhost...

```
{{item.name}}  = A+
```

And my image  =`/assets/image/A+.png`

```
  <ion-avatar item-left>
              <img src="../assets/image/{{item.name}}.png">
            </ion-avatar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used Ionic 2 a lot for iOS but not Android. For my apps I would set the src to be:

```
<img src="assets/image/{{item.name}}.png">
```

Rather than

```
<img src="../assets/image/{{item.name}}.png">
```

Comment: If you add an image called test.png into assets/images and then replace <img src="assets/image/{{item.name}}.png"> with <img src="assets/image/test.png"> then does this load?

Comment: I figured out what is problem... problem is my data value is coming A+ and in image is  assests/image/a+.png .  when i try change image name A+ and  run it with  ionic run android  it's automatically change to a+ again.....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this forum post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/images-not-displayed-on-android-device/19553)

Seems like a device is accessing assets through `/android_assets/www/<your path relative to index.html>`

Comment: I edit my question now sorry... when i try item.name = aplus   it's working well but A+ is not working i think it's from html side but i cant fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[]` to your `src` attribute otherwise your img tag is being read in the html at this exactly.

```
<img src="assets/image/{{item.name}}.png">
```

and obviously your file name is not `{{item.name}}.png` . It should be

```
<img [src]="assets/image/{{item.name}}.png">
```

to allow dynamic content.

I also think it is `../assets/image` as your `build` folder sits on the same level as your `assets` folder

Answer (score 0):

I put same image under these folders and it worked for me:

1) www/assets/img/

2) src/assests/img/

then in HTML code:

```
<img src="assets/img/image.png">
```